# rails c gives. zsh: permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am having issues since I updated my Mac OS with a recent security.  I am getting permission denied for every Rails command I run:

```
$ rails -v
zsh: permission denied: /Users/jem/Documents/Projects/Coding/Rails/

$ rails c                                                                       
zsh: permission denied: /Users/jem/Documents/Projects/Coding/Rails/

$ rails s
zsh: permission denied: /Users/jem/Documents/Projects/Coding/Rails/
```

But when I use:

```
$ bundle exec rails c
```

everything works!

This happens with every app that I have on the laptop.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you might have installed either rails or some gems with sudo. Not a great idea. `which rails` will give you the path to rails itself. Then remove the rails on the end of that and do `ls -l /path/to/rails/`. This will list out the files in the directory and their permissions. If you did this with RVM, you might try `rvm implode`. It's an easy way to start over.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I did not use sudo because I know not to but, if I copied and pasted something, who knows.

`which rails`. 
`rails: aliased to ~/Documents/Projects/Coding/Rails/`then
`ls -l | grep Rails`
`drwxr-xr-x  18 jem  admin    576 Jul 30 22:56 Rails`

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Thanks u/cowardAnnon!

I create an alias named "rails" so I can cd to that folder quickly. That was the issue. Once I commented it out, all back to normal!

Thanks to everyone.